# How to generate fpdf?

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am getting error 'Class "Fpdf" not found'.

```
use Fpdf;
Fpdf::AddPage(); 
Fpdf::SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18); 
Fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!'); 
Fpdf::Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install using Composer
   `composer require codedge/laravel-fpdf`
2. Add the following lines to your `config/app.php`

   ```
   'providers' => [
       // ...

       Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider::class,
   ],

   'aliases' => [
       // ...

       'Fpdf' => Codedge\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf::class,
   ]
   ```
3. Use it (omit `use Fpdf`):

   ```
   Fpdf::AddPage();
   Fpdf::SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
   Fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
   Fpdf::Output();
   ```

   or

   ```
   $fpdf = new Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf();
   $fpdf->AddPage();
   $fpdf->SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
   $fpdf->Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
   $fpdf->Output();
   ```